# How do I correctly use EF Core with AutoMapper ProjectTo and Unions?

Tags: c#, automapper, union, projection, ef-core-2.0

### My Setup

- ASP.NET Core 2.0
- EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1
- AutoMapper 6.2.2

---

### Problem

I have a project with a DTO called `PersonDetail` and an Entity called `Person`. 
When I call

```
db.People.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Joe").Union(db.People.Where(p => Age > 30)).ProjectTo<PersonDetail>(mapperConfig).ToList();
```

I do not get the `PersonDetail` DTOs and Entity Framework (Core) throws an exception with the message:

> ArgumentException: The input sequence must have items of type 'Test.Module.Entities.Person', but it has items of type 'Test.Module.Dtos.PersonDetail'.

---

### Example without the problem

When I run the code:

```
 db.People.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Joe").Union(db.People.Where(p => Age > 30)).ToList();
```

I get the `Person` entities with no exceptions.

---

### The Execution Plans

Here is a working plan (with a union):

> {value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Test.Module.Entities.Person]).Where(entity => ((entity != null) And ((63ed0ebd-2c02-4496-ac8d-b836cbf13259 == entity.CreatedBy) Or (393a6bb0-b437-4664-beb0-6800f509451b == entity.CreatedBy)))).Union(value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Test.Module.Entities.Person]))}

Now here is the same plan but with automapper projections too:

> {value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Test.Module.Entities.Person]).Where(entity => ((entity != null) And ((63ed0ebd-2c02-4496-ac8d-b836cbf13259 == entity.CreatedBy) Or (393a6bb0-b437-4664-beb0-6800f509451b == entity.CreatedBy)))).Union(value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Test.Module.Entities.Person])).Select(dto => new PersonDetail() {FirstName = dto.FirstName, LastName = dto.LastName, Deleted = dto.Deleted, Age = dto.Age, CreatedUtc = dto.CreatedUtc, CreatedBy = dto.CreatedBy, Id = dto.Id, RecordVersion = dto.RecordVersion, DisplayLabel = ((dto.FirstName + " ") + dto.LastName)})}

---

### Note:

I'm only calling ToList to reduce this problem to it's smallest form. I understand that this doesn't seem like I need to use ProjectTo in this example. In my actual code, we are using OData and we need the final result to be a projected query with the DTOs as Queryable objects. I also understand that this Union is not really a good union example, bu again, just for simplification of the Union problem.

Ia also opened issues on the respective GitHub projects:

**EntityFrameworkCore**: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11033

**AutoMapper**: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2537

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Thanks for this @LucianBargaoanu! This was extremely helpful and helped me to get find out that this is actually an issue with Unions. I didn't realize that my query was being manipulated further and a Union was actually a part of the plan. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an EF Core bug and it has been fixed in EF Core 2.1
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11033

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to tell exactly what is going wrong without more details, but make sure your mapping is correct, e.g. if using mapping profiles

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Person, PersonDetail>();
    }
}
```

And assuming your EF context has a set:

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

Then you should be able to query the context and project as below:

```
var details = _context.People
    .Where(p => p.LastName == 'Smith')
    .OrderBy(p => p.FirstName)
    .ProjectTo<PersonDetail>
    .ToList();
```

You don't need AsNoTracking as EF does not track result types that are not entities, see the docs on [Tracking and projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#tracking-and-projections)

--- UPDATE ---

The following should work, although EF Core will evaluate it in memory:

```
var firstNameQuery = db.People
    .Where(p => p.FirstName == "Joe")
    .ProjectTo<PersonDetail>(mapperConfig);
var ageQuery = db.People
    .Where(p => p.FirstName == "Joe")
    .ProjectTo<PersonDetail>(mapperConfig);
var results = firstNameQuery.Union(ageQuery).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisR, Thanks for the response. I've changed the issue to relate to Unions now, as we've found that this is actually what is causing our problem.

Comment: What results are you trying to get, all people with a first name of 'Joe' and are aged over 30?

Comment: No, that's just a lightweight example (I know in that example I can just use a where clause in a non-union query). The point of the example is that even a simple union won't work. We have a legitimit need for unions in some cases but I felt that added no value, just extra confusion to this question. It seems that actual unions may be broken.

Comment: Clarification, I felt it added no value to show a more complicated union as we may need to explain the data behind it and it is besides the point.